# What does it mean by `on hold`

Tags: discussion, on-hold

I recently asked a question which was given no answer. Only some edits and comments. the next day in the title a **[on hold]** was written. I didn`t understand what does it mean by [on hold]. I don't know weather it is right place to ask this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**On Hold** is a nice way of saying closed. For the first few days, it says **On Hold** before changing to **Closed**. This is just to let people know that it can be reopened, if the reason it was put On Hold is fixed. It can still be reopened after those few days, or even months later, but it's less likely as fewer people will see it then.

Answer (score 3):

As [cde notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/251318/cde) - 'on hold' indicates that the question can no longer receive answers, but in a way that conveys itself as less permanent than 'closed'.

If something is 'closed', folks think *why bother trying to fix this, it's closed!* and are less likely to attempt to clarify their question so that it can be taken off-hold. Hence, 'closed' is only applied if it  appears that the person asking the question has simply lost interest in it, or that it was a bit too far off-topic to be fixed.

They're synonymous, but they don't mean *exactly* the same thing - the wording was meant to better indicate that closure doesn't necessarily mean giving up on a question, but to put a little more time explaining it instead.